# Is there a good way to change a space delimited file to a comma delimited file?

Tags: python-3.7

I am working on a programming problem set that requires me to take space delimited input and output it through a function. I thought that if I added commas then I could make iterating through my function better.

I tried to use f.replace() and f.open('input.txt', 'r+') but it appended my output to the end of the file. I used f.open('input.txt', 'w') but I got an error that told me that the file was unreadable.

```py
def commasv():
    f = open('input.txt', 'r+')
    for x in f:
        x = x.split(' ', 2)
        f.write()
    f.close()
```

My sample input was 'C D E'. I expected the output to be 'C, D, E, ', but the output was 'C D EC, D, E, '